# split a line of data with a constraint

Tags: python, split

When I need to split a line of data I get following result:

```
>>> s="MS Dhoni cricket captain 10000"
>>> val=s.split()
>>> print val
['MS', 'Dhoni', 'cricket', 'captain', '10000']
```

But I expect code in the below manner:

```
['MS Dhoni', 'cricket', 'captain', '10000']
```

Though there is space in a specific position it must be skipped. How can I modify the code?

Comment: You cannot use `str.split()` for this at all. You *could* have some success with `re.split()` but I am doubtful. What is the *real*, complete use case here.

Comment: This isn't a bug. The method is working exactly as intended and specified.

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<!MS) ', s)`

Comment: Also please write correctly, `I` is written in upper case in English, and when pasting a code excerpt, select it and hit the `{}` button from the toolbar, or Ctrl-K on the keyboard.

Comment: There are solutions that will address this specific string, but more general solutions might require an entirely different approach.

Answer (score 2):

That code does what you want

```
import re

s="MS Dhoni cricket captain 10000"

print(re.split("\s(?=[a-z0-9])",s))
```

output:

```
['MS Dhoni', 'cricket', 'captain', '10000']
```

Explanation: split according to spaces, but only if followed by a lowercase letter or a digit (not consumed in the split operation thanks to the `?=` construction (lookahead)

BUT this is cheating: had `MS Dhoni` been in the middle of the string, it wouldn't have worked. You assume that python knows how to read a distinction (Mr, ...) or group words containing only capital letters together with the next word. That is only in your mind.

It answers your question, but you have to be more specific if you want the answer to be useful for your projects.

Comment: 100% agree with you, hence my comment in the end (and the solution in your comment works fine too, although I'll have to look it up to understand what it is doing exactly :))

Comment: It might end up helping, but a more general solution is essentially entity extraction/recognition.